# Cannot Use OpenCV With -std=c++0x/gnu++0x in Fuerte

Tags: opencv, ros-fuerte, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compiling against OpenCV/FLANN in Fuerte/Ubuntu 12.04 amd64/gcc4.6 fails when using -std=c++0x due to [this issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2179) which has yet to be integrated into ROS; are there plans to pull this fix into ROS any time soon?

For example, the following simple test program:

> #include <opencv/cv.h>

> int main(){ return 0; }

when compiled with:

> g++ opencv_test.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -std=c++0x

will fail with:

> error: ‘use_speed_’ was not declared in this scope

So far, I've been able to fix this issue by grabbing the latest OpenCV source (I'm using 2.4.9; issue was fixed in 2.4.3) and compiling/installing with:

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte

> make

> sudo make install

which appears to solve the issue, but is far from ideal. Are there any alternative workarounds for this issue?  As far as I can tell, it is currently not possible to compile any code requiring both OpenCV and the c++0x/gnu++0x flag in fuerte out-of-the-box.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46723/cannot-use-opencv-with--std=c++0x/gnu++0x-in-fuerte/) by [ekaszubski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3455/ekaszubski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV 2.4.3 just came out, so I went ahead and just packaged it myself and added provides/conflicts/replaces fields for ros-fuerte-opencv2 and ros-groovy-opencv2 (so no compiling from source, and it automatically uninstalls/replaces the existing ros-<version>-opencv2 package in a clean way).

I tested the packages on my precise+fuerte cleanroom and the basic program above compiles as expected; however, I have yet to test it with rosbuild. Presumably, since the opencv2 ros package (provided by vision-opencv) uses pkg-config to grab the cflags and libs, the flags from 2.4.3 should be pulled in and everything should just work.

So if anyone is interested, the debs (libopencv2.4 and libopencv2.4-dev, both version 2.4.3) for oneiric and precise are [here](http://robotics.usc.edu/%7Eekaszubski/packages/ubuntu/), and setup instructions for the PPA are [here](http://code.google.com/p/usc-interaction-software/wiki/UbuntuPPA).

---

Originally posted by [ekaszubski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3455/ekaszubski/) with karma: 101 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-06**:
Cool! Could you select your answer so it shows up as answered?

**Comment by [ekaszubski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3455/ekaszubski/) on 2012-11-06**:
I marked this as answered since my solution technically works, but the best solution would be to update ros-fuerte/groovy-opencv2 to OpenCV 2.4.3.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-06**:
Well, as of (now) it looks like ros-groovy-opencv2 is at 2.4.3, and ros-fuerte-opencv2 is at 2.4.2 (:

**Comment by [ekaszubski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3455/ekaszubski/) on 2012-11-07**:
Good to know that groovy is up-to-date; hopefully fuerte will be updated soon as well. Thanks for the info!

**Comment by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on 2013-04-03**:
2.4.3 for fuerte is not yet available, and I don't have access to [http://robotics.usc.edu/~ekaszubski/packages/ubuntu/](http://robotics.usc.edu/%7Eekaszubski/packages/ubuntu/) :-(